# ubuntu: /root partition size does not change after extending with Gparted

Tags: ubuntu, root, partitioning

I cloned my hard-drive and extended the root partition using GParted (with live-cd). But when I boot into ubuntu, the extra size does not show up.

After searching around, I am lost as nothing has worked. Any suggestion/opinion at this point is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Consider asking over at https://askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the file system was not grown to fill the partition.  If this is the case then run `gparted` (best done from live media so no partitions are mounted), select the partition and choose **Partition -> Check**, then **Edit -> Apply**.  This should grow the file system to fill the partition.

However, if the partition uses **L**ogical **V**olume **M**anagment (lvm2 pv), then you will need to use commands like `lvresize` to grow the Logical Volume within the Physical Volume.